# Rails App - Display Customer Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that tracks movie rentals. I have a relationship established between my Rentals table and my Customers table. Each rentals is associated with one customer.

In the new view for rentals, I have a table that displays all rentals and their basic information. I want to display the customers name is the row for each rental. Right now I have r.customer_id, which pulls the customer_id for the rental. But I want the NAME of that person. Here is my view for "new" rentals:

```
<h4 class='white'>Rental Records</h4>
<% if @movie.rentals.exists? %>
<div class="bg_white">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Borrowed</th>
        <th>Returned</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <% for r in @movie.rentals.order(borrowed_on: :desc) %> 
        <% if !r.borrowed_on.nil? %>
            <% if r.returned_on.nil? %>
                <tr class="red">
                    <td>
                        <%= r.borrowed_on %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= r.returned_on %> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= r.customer_id %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= link_to "Update", edit_movie_rental_path(@movie, r) %> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= link_to "Delete", movie_rental_path(@movie, r), method: :delete %> 
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <% else %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= r.borrowed_on %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= r.returned_on %> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= r.customer_id %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= link_to "Update", edit_movie_rental_path(@movie, r) %> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= link_to "Delete", movie_rental_path(@movie, r), method: :delete %> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>   
        <% end %>
    <% end %> 
</table>
</div>
<% else %>
<p class="white"><i>No rentals to show</i><br /><br /></p>
<% end %>
```

Rentals model:

```
class Rental < ApplicationRecord
has_one :movie
has_one :customer
end
```

Customer model:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
has_many :rentals 

def full_name
    "#{self.fname} #{self.lname}"
end 
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :customers

resources :movies do 
resources :rentals
end 
root 'movies#new'
end
```

Customers controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
def new
@customer = Customer.new 
@customers = Customer.all.order(lname: :asc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15) 
end

def create
@customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
if @customer.save 
  redirect_to new_customer_path
end 
end

def edit
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@customer.update(customer_params)
if @customer.save 
  redirect_to new_customer_path
end
end

def destroy
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@customer.destroy
if @customer.destroy
  redirect_to new_customer_path 
end 
end

private 

def customer_params
params.require(:customer).permit(:fname, :lname, :telephone, :email)
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use belongs_to on model Rental?

In my opinion

```
class Rental < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rentals 

  def full_name
    "#{self.fname} #{self.lname}"
  end 
end
```

and on the view you can call

```
<%= r.customer.full_name %>
```

With above code, I think has_one still work, but belongs_to is better

Answer (score 3):

You can do `r.customer.name` although that violates the law of demeter, so you can (preferred) do

```
delegate :name, to: :customer, prefix: true
```

in the rental model and then do

```
r.customer_name
```